# Run maven project-info-reports:dependencies with a pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I want to include my dependencies.html into a warfile in a multi module project. When i run mvn project-info-reports:dependencies the folder site gets created with the dependencies.html file in it. Is there a way to do this with a pom.xml file?
Things that did not work have been:

```
<build>
  <finalName>some-module</finalName>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>dependencies</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            ...
```

or this one:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>index</report>
                        <report>dependencies</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

<build>
  <finalName>some-module</finalName>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>dependencies</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            ...
```

There is no error message in the logs, it just gets skipped. Am i doing something wrong here or is it just not meant to execute with the pom.xml?

Comment: Why would you like to have a report in your war file?

Comment: I like this place to control all project dependencies and licenses.

Comment: That will not control the dependencies nor the licenses ..it will make only a report about it...The question is: What kind of control would like to do?

Comment: Thats right it does not control anything. But the war file is an ok place for me to look at the report and control all of the dependencies and licenses. Is there a reason for your questions?

Comment: The question is: What exactly would you like to control cause manually no one really does...and my opinion is: just putting a report into a war does not really solve anything...

Comment: All the licenses we use in our project. Are they free, ...